# Why can't I use a function call to declare the length of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, strlen

This is what I am trying to do:

```
const char wav_folder[] = ".\\wav";
const char search_path[strlen(wav_folder) + 6];
```

but the strlen part is not allowing me to create this character array. This is not compiling. Why?

Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2057: expected constant expression   c:\users\hassan\documents\cpp\dir_search\dir_search\dir_search\source.cpp   15  1   dir_search
Error   2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    c:\users\hassan\documents\cpp\dir_search\dir_search\dir_search\source.cpp   15  1   dir_search
Error   3   error C2734: 'search_path' : const object must be initialized if not extern c:\users\hassan\documents\cpp\dir_search\dir_search\dir_search\source.cpp   15  1   dir_search
Error   4   error C2133: 'search_path' : unknown size   c:\users\hassan\documents\cpp\dir_search\dir_search\dir_search\source.cpp   15  1   dir_search
```

Comment: what does you compiler say?

Comment: Strlen is a function. I'm not sure if recent C compilers (for C11) would let it, but sizeof() has been working for decades. Just be aware of ending 0.

Comment: same example runs fine: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen

Comment: well, it seems that I have learnt something new from this trivial example. I was quite perplexed by this error. Yes, I am electronic engineer, not used to writing this code.

Comment: Do you have any interest in accepting one of the 3 answers you were given?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of arrays is created at **compile** time. `strlen()` and all other functions run at **runtime**.

Because of that, the compiler doesn't know how long the string will be when it allocates space in the final executable for `const char search_path`.

You need to do one of the following:

- use `sizeof`, as in `const char search_path[sizeof(wav_folder) + 6];` (thanks, guys! I forgot about that...),
- manually insert the total length for `search_path.` For instance,
  `const char search_path[13];`,
- dynamically allocate an array at runtime (using `new` and, when you're finished with it, freeing the memory it occupies with `new`'s counterpart `delete` / `delete[]`,
- *or* `#define` the necessary length for `searchpath`. Macros are evaluated/substituted at compile time. Therefore, you would define the necessary length like this:
  `#define SEARCH_PATH_LEN 13`

Comment: #define dir_l_1 strlen(".\\wav") simply does not work

Comment: @quantum231: Sorry, I wasn't clearer about that point. I've edited my answer to explain what I meant. Basically, `const char search_path[ dir_l_1 + 6];` gets turned into `const char search_path[ strlen(".\\wav") + 6];` before it is compiled. As you can see, that is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to dynamically allocate an array you should new operator new. 
This is "stack" allocation - you can't use functions to determine the size when you declare it.

The compiler wants to know the size in advance - to put it on the stack and not on the heap, and when you use the function - it can't tell what the size is (before the function is being called.

Comment: How about `std::string` so we do not have to worry about `delete` later on?

Comment: I was referring the use of a function to declare an array on the stack. of course string will be easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is exactly spelled by 1st error text - "**expected constant expression**"

Declaration of arrays in C/C++ requires *constant expression* between `[` and `]`, ie an expression that can be evaluated (computed) at compile time. Result of `strlen()` is not known at compile time, so it cannot be used (because it's run-time function) but you can replace it with `sizeof()`:

`const char search_path[sizeof(wav_folder) + 6];`

**EDIT** (Following comments below) The constant expression is not required if array is allocated on stack, but array in the question is allocated in static memory, thus this error. Other useful details are in NathanOliver's comment below

Comment: *Declaration of arrays in C/C++ requires constant expression between [ and ]* This is not true for C11 which has VLA's in the standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you for this information, I didn't know that, will search and learn. But still, it is obvious that OP's compiler (or its settings) doesn't support this VLA - the error text is clearly indicates it, as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: True.  I just wanted to point out that C now allows runtime size for "static" arrays.

Comment: @NathanOliver googling for this I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) that VLA was supported even by C99 and now I recall that I myself used it some years ago.... This makes my answer wrong and I will now edit it